# I want loop in select box according radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have task in which when I select 12 hour radio button then value of drop down change  according to am and pm and if i am selecting 24 hours radio button then drop down value is 1 to 24. i am able to achive this task but now value of select box display throught loop. how can achive this.

My code is:

```
<select class="describe">
    <option name="name" value="1">select type</option>

  </select>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="class" name="type" value="1" checked>12 hour <br/>
  <input type="radio" id="Club" name="type" value="2" >24 hour<br/>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
<script>
    var listA = [
        { name: '1am', value: '1am' }, 
        { name: '2am', value: '2am' }, 
        { name: '3am', value: '3am' }
    ];
    var listB = [
        { name: '12', value: '12' }, 
        { name: '13', value: '13' }, 
        { name: '14', value: '14' }
    ];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#class').bind('click', function () {
            $('.describe').empty();
            $.each(listA, function (index, value) {
                $('.describe').append(
                    '<option value="' + value.value + '">' + value.name + '</option>'
                );
            });
        });
        $('#Club').bind('click', function () {
            $('.describe').empty();
            $.each(listB, function (index, value) {
                $('.describe').append(
                    '<option value="' + value.value + '">' + value.name + '</option>'
                );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

loop for select code(which was tried by me):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.seconds').each(function () {
        for (var i = 00; i <= 60; i++) {
            $('<option />').val(i).html('  ' + i).appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is the element with the class "seconds" in your html code?

Comment: for second 1 to 60 ...

Comment: jwulf means there is no `seconds` in the html

Comment: <select class="seconds"></select>  its simply a select box.

Comment: Is this you required?

Answer (score 0):

Should work this way:

```
    function fillHoursSelect(mode) {
        if(mode === 24) {
            $('.describe').each(function() {
                for(i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
                    $('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>').appendTo($(this));
                }
            });
        }
        else if(mode === 12) {
            $('.describe').each(function() {
                for(i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                    $('<option value="' + i + 'am">' + i + 'am</option>').appendTo($(this));
                }
                for(i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                    $('<option value="' + i + 'pm">' + i + 'pm</option>').appendTo($(this));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $('#Club').bind('click', function () {
        $('.describe').empty();
        fillHoursSelect(24);
    });
    $('#class').bind('click', function () {
        $('.describe').empty();
        fillHoursSelect(12);
    });
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beecA/)

Comment: Or did I get your question wrong and the seconds-thing is already working and you want the same thing for the hours-part?

Comment: yes your ans is right but its not my question .my Question is when i click on 12 hour then my dropdown value change thought select loop instead of (var listA = [
        { name: '1am', value: '1am' }, 
        { name: '2am', value: '2am' }, 
        { name: '3am', value: '3am' }
    ];) add manually . same for 24 hour.

Comment: Edited the answer. That what you looking for?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the am/pm-system so if 12am and 12pm are wrong you might need to check/change that. But you could to that on your own, right?

Comment: Ah sorry I accidentally rejected the edit (or didn't I do that at all? not familiar yet with the edit-system...) which changed the seconds-class to descdribe in my code.
The fiddle provided by @A.Kalkhoff works however since there the class-names are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setupHourOptions(selectElement, format)
{
    var list = "";
    list +="<option value='-1'>select type</option>"
    for(var i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
    {
        var isAm = (Math.floor(i / 12) == 0);
        var hoursAmPm = (i % 12);
        if(hoursAmPm == 0) hoursAmPm = 12; 
        list +="<option value='" + i + "'>"
        list += format == '12h' 
        ? hoursAmPm + (isAm ? " am" : " pm" )
        : i;

        list +="</option>\n";

    }
    selectElement.html(list);
}

$(document).ready(
    function (){
        var hourFormatSelect = $("select.describe");
        $("input[name='hourformat']:radio").change(
             function ()
            {
                setupHourOptions(hourFormatSelect, this.value);
            }            
          );

        // set up default format at load
        var defaultFormat = $("input[name='hourformat']:checked").val();
        setupHourOptions(hourFormatSelect, defaultFormat);
    }
);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqG4F/)